# generate sample from pareto,log normal, exponential and weibull distribution with the same mean

Tags: matlab, distribution, sample

How i can generate random variable Z from various distribution with the same mean `E[Z]=10^9` in matlab
-weibull 
-log normal 
-exponential 
-pareto
! Z is a variable of size 200
thanks

```
F=200
if distr == 1
zf = exprnd(10^9,1,F); % Exponential
elseif distr==2
alphap=20/19;
beta=0.05*10^9;
zf=beta* rand([1, F]).^(-1/alphap);  % Pareto  
elseif distr==3
mi=276;
k=0.1;
zf=wblrnd(mi,k,[1, F]); % Weibull
elseif distr==4
mu=5*log2(10);
sigma=sqrt(8*log2(10));
zf=lognrnd(mu,sigma, [1, F]); %Lognormal
end
```

This code didn't give me a good result

Comment: What is wrong with the results? Why are they bad?

Comment: zf6=wblrnd(mi,k,1,10)

zf6 =

   1.0e+06 *

  Columns 1 through 9

    0.0000    2.0304    0.0000    0.0008    0.0000    0.0000    0.0828    0.2231    0.0000

  Column 10

    1.2788

Comment: No, you missed the scaling factor `1.0e+06`

Comment: i need to generate sample of order statistics of each distribution ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. To explain my previous comment a little more, it is simply not true that all your values are zero. For example the `0.0008` is displayed with a scaling factor of `1.0e+06` which means it is a `800`. If you don't like that visualisation, read the doc for `format` and choose the one you like.

Comment: my problem exactely is to generate ordered statistics from various distributions as (weibull, log normal....)

Comment: Please read [ask]. Describe what is wrong with your code, the only problem description you gave is "all result are zero". but that is obviously not true.